# Replace icons in dll c#

Tags: c#, dll, icons

How could I replace one or more icons in a dll file without affecting the others in c#?

I only know one method to get icons from a dll file, not to replace them.

Could anyone help me?
A thousand thanks!

Comment: Well, the best way to do it is to rebuild the DLL from the original source project.  Since I assume you don't have the original source, have you tried searching the Internet for tools that do this?  [My first attempt](https://www.google.com/search?q=replace+icons+in+DLL) resulted in [this](https://www.gdgsoft.com/gconvert/help/Modify_Icons_EXE.htm).

Comment: If you want to do it in code, [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30644/Replacing-ICON-resources-in-EXE-and-DLL-files).